# android-inflate using the layout-inflater

Tags: discussion, tags

I found that [layout-inflater](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/layout-inflater) and [android-inflate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-inflate) is referring to the same objective: Android inflater mechanism. Can we merge them?

Comment: It would seem to me that it would be fine.  As far as I know, only Android uses "inflation" as a term for layouts.

Comment: `LayoutInflater` is a name of the class